# Missing Xutf8LookupString call in Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, x11, unicode

I'm trying to run a program in Solaris 10 that fails due to the lack of `Xutf8LookupString` function.

It is a well-known issue but I'd like to know a way to "skip it".

Would defining a different non-utf8 `LC_CTYPE` help?

Would installing a different X server help? 
The problem doesn't happen on OpenSolaris.

Is there a way I can "update" my Solaris system to use the same X libs as an OpenSolaris one?

Comment: You mean `Xutf8LookupString`, right (case is important)? What is the program? What is the exact error message? What happens if you do try `LC_CTYPE=en_US` or `LC_CTYPE=C`?

Comment: Edited name. Thanks. With LC_CTYPE=C (default) I get exactly the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is in libX11 - changing X servers won't make a difference.   Without seeing the program's source, we can't guess if changing locale settings would stop it from calling the function, but changing locale won't stop the linker from trying to find it in a library.

The only way to get a libX11 for Solaris 10 or older with that function in is to build libX11 yourself.   It won't be fully compatible with existing X binaries though.   Sun/Oracle have never backported the new libX11 from OpenSolaris/Solaris 11 to the older releases.

Comment: So, Solaris 11 will get this fixed?? I will give it a try then. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Solaris 11 is building on the sources from OpenSolaris and has the X11R7 versions of the X libraries which include this function, not the older X11R6.6 ones that were found in Solaris 10.